# How can I run Spring MVC application on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, heroku

I have simple application on Spring MVC which runned on tomcat 7.0.72 in IDEA. How can I run this application on Heroku (if it's possible). I have Heroku account and I did create app on it. I use Maven for deploy and Git for push it in Heroku. Files of app will be below. So, when I run it on localhost by tomcat it works. But when I push it on heroku I get it:

> Application Error:
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mardmitry</groupId>
    <artifactId>bestmuzon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>BestMuzon</name>
    <!--<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>-->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-framework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring-framework-version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.6</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JSF (include "jsf-api" and "jsf-impl")-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>https://bestmuzonproject.herokuapp.com/</url>
                    <!--<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>-->
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/mkyongWebApp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Structure of my app:
[Structure of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu9BW.png)

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <!-- Создает Spring Container, доступный всем сервлетам и фильтрам -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Обрабатывает все запросы. Центральное понятие-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

MainController:

```
package com.mardmitry.controllers;

import com.mardmitry.model.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView main() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("userJSP", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    /*как только на index.jsp подтвердится форма
    <spring:form method="post"  modelAttribute="userJSP" action="check-user">,
    то попадем вот сюда
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/check-user")
    public ModelAndView checkUser(@ModelAttribute("userJSP") User user) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();   
        modelAndView.setViewName("secondPage");
        modelAndView.addObject("userJSP", user);

        return modelAndView; 
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Best Muzon</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <spring:form method="post"  modelAttribute="userJSP" action="check-user">

      Name: <spring:input path="name"/> (path="" - указывает путь, используемый в modelAttribute=''. в нашем случае User.name)  <br/>
      Password: <spring:input path="password"/>   <br/>
      <spring:button>Next Page</spring:button>

  </spring:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Build log in Git:

```
Counting objects: 359, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (282/282), done.
Writing objects: 100% (359/359), 20.70 MiB | 99.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 359 (delta 130), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
remote: -----> Executing: mvn -B -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Building BestMuzon 1.0-SNAPSHOT
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Deleting /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/target
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:list (default-cli) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/src/main/resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/target/classes
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/src/test/resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] No sources to compile
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Tests are skipped.
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/target/bestmuzon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:copy (default) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Configured Artifact: com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.0.30.2:jar
remote:        [INFO] Copying webapp-runner-8.0.30.2.jar to /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ bestmuzon ---
remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/target/bestmuzon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/mardmitry/bestmuzon/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bestmuzon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_90aea2b2f1ce2e21c7e6a87e78ae382d/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/mardmitry/bestmuzon/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bestmuzon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 3.629 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-20T10:34:05+00:00
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/171M
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 70M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v23
remote:        https://bestmuzonproject.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/bestmuzonproject.git
 + 8306e15...83a9a0c master -> master (forced update)
```

Heroku logs:

```
2016-10-20T10:34:13.261601+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 83a9a0c by arxangel192@mail.ru
2016-10-20T10:34:13.261601+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v23 created by arxangel192@mail.ru
2016-10-20T10:34:13.409620+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-20T10:34:13.409611+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-20T10:34:13.962566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-10-20T10:34:13.963376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-10-20T10:34:16.874279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-10-20T10:34:17.556730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2016-10-20T10:34:18.183328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-10-20T10:34:19.795333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-20T10:34:19.796435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-20T10:34:19.682528+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-10-20T10:34:19.686998+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 0: Can't open target/bin/webapp
2016-10-20T10:34:19.777080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-10-20T10:34:23.291738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/webapp`
2016-10-20T10:34:24.945775+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-10-20T10:34:24.946678+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 0: Can't open target/bin/webapp
2016-10-20T10:34:25.024482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-20T10:34:25.009062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-10-20T10:34:57.262474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bestmuzonproject.herokuapp.com request_id=1acd63ba-7e38-4279-881c-2eb1a1708a63 fwd="178.94.207.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-20T10:35:38.838802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bestmuzonproject.herokuapp.com request_id=cafaddfe-5c81-4d00-a47d-9c1111d6053b fwd="178.94.207.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Here is the guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate

Comment: I saw that and tried to do it. But app error. And in it guide app wrote in different maner/type.

Comment: What does it show in logs?

Comment: I added build log from Git to question.

Comment: Have you added a procfile?

Comment: Yes. In main dirrectory with code: web: sh target/bin/webapp

Comment: This is already well documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) two deployment styles for Java web applications:

The first is detailed here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

The second is detailed here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner

You seem to have mixed elements of both mechanisms in your POM: for example the webapp-runner is only required in the second style.

Remove these conflicts and check the configuration.

Comment: So, I can't create app which can be run in IDEA by tomcat and on heroku?

Comment: I try to do it in second way.

Comment: You can deploy from IDEA : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea   OR read spring boot in action chapter 8

Comment: I want to buid app with Spring and mapping but not on servlets